# Python lxml web scraping: xpath isn't working

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to get all of the links associated with doctors' names from [here](http://www.cpsnl.ca/default.asp?adv=1&com=DoctorSearch&selComm=&txtFName=&Certification_Code_Desc=&txtLName=&NameHidden=all&offset=0). I think there's something wrong with my XPath, but I'm not sure what.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

    page = requests.get('http://www.cpsnl.ca/default.asp?adv=1&com=DoctorSearch&selComm=&txtFName=&Certification_Code_Desc=&txtLName=&NameHidden=all&offset=0')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


    links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main_con"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a')
    print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

There would not be `tbody` element in the HTML that requests would download for you. `tbody` is something a browser usually creates. Fixed XPath expression (pointing it to `href` additionally):

```
//*[@id="main_con"]/table//tr/td/a/@href
```